# How To Remove Link From Browsers' "View Page Source" feature?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a simple password protected webpage that provides the link to another webpage when we enter the correct password but we can easily have the webadrress of other page by browsers "View Page Source" feature.So how we can overcome this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you render your page with secret link you wont to show if credentials are correct. If so, answer is quite simple - do not store your secrets directly in the page. Send credentials to the beckend, and show the result if password is correct.

Comment: How could we do that?Could you please help?

Comment: @RajatAggarwal Learn PHP; there's no other way.

Comment: @ChrisG Why PHP only? BE can be done with dosen of languages - starting fro Visual Basic and ending Huskell. For TC I'll suggest Node.Js as far as it uses JavaScript

Comment: @Drag13 "there's no other way" was referring to "using a backend", not PHP, given that there's tons of other ways obviously.

Comment: @ChrisG then, please take my appologizes

Comment: The only way is to learn a backend language. PHP, Python and tons of other are available for it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are keeping your secret data on the client and client can easily reach it. So, the only posible way for you is to keep them on the server. But, as far as I understand you need help with server part. So here is small instruction with links to the documentation.

You will need:

- Some backend that will take data from your users and returns some responce. I would suggest you to have a look into [Node.Js](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/) as a platform with [Express](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm) as a server. Benefit from this setup is that Node.Js uses JavaScript so you have not to learn additional language, and Express is a very simple server to use. Of course, if you want to learn some other languages - you can take C# with ASP.NET MVC framework, PHP or any other nice language.
- Some page with form for user's credentials that will post data to your backend. Basic form behavior can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)
- And some code on server that will validate credentials from form and return new page with or without your secret.

That's it. May be it sound a bit scary but there are lots of [guides](https://mfranc.com/node-js/node-js-simple-web-server-with-express/) and information your can google.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

---

Btw, if you are lloking for the some ready code, I have Node.JS client/server example with TypeScript (JavaScript with type validation) [here](https://github.com/Drag13/typescript-browserify-template). All you need is [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads), hope you already have it, and [Node.Js](https://nodejs.org/uk/)

Then just execute this commands on your console (bash, cmd, etc)

> git clone https://github.com/Drag13/typescript-browserify-template

This will download code from remote server to your local machine

> npm install

Installs project dependencies - like express server

> npm run server

Starts the server

> cd..
>   npm run client

Starts the client

Maybe you will find this helpfull.